# How to apply ODR(One Definition Rule) in c++?

Tags: c++

I read the page [Definitions and ODR](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) and I also read several relevant questions about ODR. Still don't understand why it is important.

For example, in file1.cpp:

```
int val = 1;
```

In file2.cpp:

```
int val = 2;
```

In main.cpp:

```
extern int val;
```

This case violates the ODR. But in real cases, will anyone do this? I mean one definition for a variable with the same name of the same type seems to be something natural. Even if someone did this, compiler or linker won't agree.  I don't understand why we should care about ODR because if we write the wrong code, compiler or linker will give the error. Is it possible to violate ODR without being detected? Can anyone list some real cases or mistakes we often make?

Comment: The compiler might not give you any error at all. odr-violation leads to undefined behaviour, so your program is allowed to do anything and everything.

Comment: "These code can't be compiled" - Oh yes they can be. They should not be linkable, however.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Probably true in this case, but in some very similar cases, it may even link without problems. Don't trust the linker to detect all ODR violations.

Comment: @hvd That's why I said "should not", and not "will not".

Comment: @NeilButterworth I have corrected my description. Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't understand why should we care about ODR because if we write the wrong code, compiler will give error.

The ODR is the only thing allowing compilers to issue an error message. If we didn't have the ODR, compilers would be required to accept such code.

> Is it possible to violate ODR while the code can be compiled?

Sure. Depending on the compiler, this may compile and link without any problems, or it may fail:

```
extern int var;
int main() {
  int myvar = var;
}
```

Note the lack of a definition of `var` here.

Some compilers see that the local variable `myvar` is completely unused, and therefore remove the reference to `var` as well. Other compilers/linkers will complain about the missing definition of `var`. And for yet some others, it depends on which compiler flags you pass.

Another example:

```
// t1.cc
int var;
```

```
// t2.cc
long var;
```

Some compilers give `int var` and `long var` the same internal name and detect the conflict, other compilers include the type and don't see any conflict.

Comment: It's down to the linker to detect these problems, not the compiler. The compiler cannot see values in translation units other than the one it is currently compiling.

Comment: @NeilButterworth It's the compiler that provides sufficient information to the linker to detect errors. It's the compiler that optimises away the reference to `var` in my first example, that's not the linker's doing. And ODR also covers `int var; int var;`, which is normally detected by the compiler rather than the linker. Regardless, the distinction between compiler and linker is no longer a relevant one, I think, now that compilers are implementing LTO and thereby taking over part of what was traditionally the linker's work.

Comment: You seem a bit confused about the two  to me - for example, I can't see why you think your first code example may fail at compile-time.

Comment: @NeilButterworth "you think your first code example may fail at compile-time"? That's not what I wrote.

Comment: " this may compile and link without any problems, or it may fail:" - I would have added "at link time".  Your answer really confuses compile and link time for the reader, IMHO.

Comment: The first example seems not that dangerous. Does "other compilers include the type" mean that type is part of the internal name?

Comment: @faivvy Sometimes, because some compilers accept it, people don't realise they've written invalid code until others attempt to build it using their own preferred toolchain, sometimes years later when the original people are no longer around to fix the bug. I could try to find another example if you were after something else, but if so, please explain what. "Does "other compilers include the type" mean that type is part of the internal name?" Yes, for those compilers. Specifically: if you're familiar with the term "name mangling", the type is included in the mangled name in some implementations

Comment: @hvd One more question, detecting and preventing the violation is the programmers' duty, not compiler's or linker's, so the compiler and linker do not promise any thing though sometimes they will give errors. Is that why you said "don't trust the linker"?

Comment: @faivvy Yes. In general, when you get a warning or error about an ODR violation, you can generally trust that the message is correct, but you should not infer anything from the lack of diagnostics, your code could still have undetected ODR violations.

Answer (score 2):

### Small note on fixing the case

You can declare such variable as `static` in the translation unit, or within an anonymous namespace.

`static` global variables do have internal linkage and thus do not violate ODR.

file1.cpp

```
 static int val = 1;
 // OR
 namespace
 {
   int val = 1;
 }
```

file2.cpp

```
static int val = 2;
// OR
namespace
{
  int val = 2;
}
```

### Potential Case from Real Life

What if you have 2 DLLs, or SOs both featuring the same global variable and you load both shared libs in your application?

Comment: I want to know how we will make mistakes which can't be detected by compiler or linker.